# How to access https in Android Application

Tags: android, video, cordova, https, vimeo

I am trying to access Vimeo Player within my PhoneGap/Android App. Here is my HTML:

```
var sVidFile = document.getElementById("popupVideo");
var sLink = "82299487";
sVidFile.innerHTML = '<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + sLink + '" ' + 'seamless></iframe>';
$.mobile.changePage("#VideoPage");
```

It runs OK in the emulator but when I run it on my Android Phone it gives this error:

```
Application Error
There was a network error (https://player.vimeo.com/video/82299487)
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong (or need to do right!)?

Thanks

EDIT:

I have tried other Video IDs also with the same result.

I have partially solved the problem by adding this to config.xml:

```
<access origin="https://player.vimeo.com/*" />
```

However only a window appears but No video shows up. Even the Video controls are not visible.

Comment: check internet permission & network is exist in your device or not ?

Comment: Yes I am able to use all internet services on my device.

Comment: okay try with some other video id or URL

Comment: is ur android device version(api) and emulator version(api ) is same or diff.?

Comment: Please see my Edit above

Comment: For Emulator I am simply using "RippleSites"